# Replace For Loop to fill column depending on other column value

Tags: r

I have a two-column dataframe (HOME & AWAY) called 'gamelist' with sports games. The HOME column also includes some dates with the corresponding games listed below.

```
HOME               AWAY  
15 Oct 2019        Pre-season  
Phoenix Suns       Denver Nuggets
Utah Jazz          Sacramento Kings
Dallas Mavericks   Oklahoma City Thunder
Memphis Grizzlies  Charlotte Hornets
14 Oct 2019        Pre-season
Miami Heat         Atlanta Hawks
13 Oct 2019        Pre-season
Orlando Magic      Philadelphia 76ers
Toronto Raptors    Chicago Bulls
Washington Wizards Milwaukee Bucks
```

I want to create a new column with the dates for each game. Coming from a excel vba approach, I've used a for loop which is giving the result intented but I was wondering if there was a more efficient approach in R, and I'm sure there is.

This is the code I've used:

```
gamelist<-add_column(gamelist,SDATE="",.before = 1)
for(i in 1:nrow(gamelist)){
  if(str_count(gamelist[[i,3]],"\\d")==6){
    gamelist[i,2]<-gamelist[i,3]

  }else{
    gamelist[i,2]<-gamelist[i-1,2]  
  }
}
```

Which gives me this as intended

```
SDATE              HOME               AWAY 
15 Oct 2019        15 Oct 2019        Pre-season  
15 Oct 2019        Phoenix Suns       Denver Nuggets
15 Oct 2019        Utah Jazz          Sacramento Kings
15 Oct 2019        Dallas Mavericks   Oklahoma City Thunder
15 Oct 2019        Memphis Grizzlies  Charlotte Hornets
14 Oct 2019        14 Oct 2019        Pre-season
14 Oct 2019        Miami Heat         Atlanta Hawks
13 Oct 2019        13 Oct 2019        Pre-season
13 Oct 2019        Orlando Magic      Philadelphia 76ers
13 Oct 2019        Toronto Raptors    Chicago Bulls
13 Oct 2019        Washington Wizards Milwaukee Bucks
```

My apologies for the dataframe formatting, couldn't figure out how to reproduce one properly here.
Thanks for your help

Comment: The best data format to post in a question is the output of `dput(gamelist)`.

Comment: Well this is the output of gamelist

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry just understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` to get only the 'dates' so that if there is no match it returns NA, then we use `fill` to fill the NA elements with the previous non-NA values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
gamelist %>%
      mutate(SDATE = str_extract(HOME, "^\\d+ [A-Za-z]+ \\d{4}")) %>%
      fill(SDATE)
#             HOME                  AWAY       SDATE
#1         15 Oct 2019            Pre-season 15 Oct 2019
#2        Phoenix Suns        Denver Nuggets 15 Oct 2019
#3           Utah Jazz      Sacramento Kings 15 Oct 2019
#4    Dallas Mavericks Oklahoma City Thunder 15 Oct 2019
#5   Memphis Grizzlies     Charlotte Hornets 15 Oct 2019
#6         14 Oct 2019            Pre-season 14 Oct 2019
#7          Miami Heat         Atlanta Hawks 14 Oct 2019
#8         13 Oct 2019            Pre-season 13 Oct 2019
#9       Orlando Magic    Philadelphia 76ers 13 Oct 2019
#10    Toronto Raptors         Chicago Bulls 13 Oct 2019
#11 Washington Wizards       Milwaukee Bucks 13 Oct 2019
```

If we need the `SDATE` column first, we can use `select`

```
gamelist %>%
      mutate(SDATE = str_extract(HOME, "^\\d+ [A-Za-z]+ \\d{4}")) %>%
      fill(SDATE) %>%
      select(SDATE, everything())
```

Or use `add_column` from `tibble` with either `.after` or `.before`

```
library(tibble)
gamelist %>%
    add_column(SDATE = str_extract(.$HOME, "^\\d+ [A-Za-z]+ \\d{4}"), 
            .before = 1 ) %>% 
    fill(SDATE)
```

#### data

```
gamelist <- structure(list(HOME = c("15 Oct 2019", "Phoenix Suns", "Utah Jazz", 
"Dallas Mavericks", "Memphis Grizzlies", "14 Oct 2019", "Miami Heat", 
"13 Oct 2019", "Orlando Magic", "Toronto Raptors", "Washington Wizards"
), AWAY = c("Pre-season", "Denver Nuggets", "Sacramento Kings", 
"Oklahoma City Thunder", "Charlotte Hornets", "Pre-season", "Atlanta Hawks", 
"Pre-season", "Philadelphia 76ers", "Chicago Bulls", "Milwaukee Bucks"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: How would you specify the column SDATE to appear fisrt?

Comment: @M.O either you can use `select` afterwards or make use of `add_column`, but the

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always in the HOME column when the AWAY column is "Pre-season" (or some other predictable condition), then you could do something like:

```
# data
gamelist <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              HOME = c("15-Oct-19","Phoenix Suns",
                       "Utah Jazz","Dallas Mavericks","Memphis Grizzlies",
                       "14-Oct-19","Miami Heat","13-Oct-19","Orlando Magic",
                       "Toronto Raptors","Washington Wizards"),
              AWAY = c("Pre-season","Denver Nuggets",
                       "Sacramento Kings","Oklahoma City Thunder",
                       "Charlotte Hornets","Pre-season","Atlanta Hawks","Pre-season",
                       "Philadelphia 76ers","Chicago Bulls","Milwaukee Bucks")
)

# create blank column to fill in 
gamelist$date <- NA
# fill cases where there's a date 
gamelist$date[gamelist$AWAY=="Pre-season"] <- gamelist$HOME[gamelist$AWAY=="Pre-season"]
# user zoo::na.locf() to fill in missing values
gamelist$date <- zoo::na.locf(gamelist$date)
```